# Swagger Api Documentation - Model List<Enum>

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

How should this class be modeled for [Swagger](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/) to interpret it properly?

```
public myEnum {
    alpha,
    bravo,
    charlie
}

public class myClass {
    public List<myEnum> myList { get; set; }
}
```

I can't simply do this:

```
{
    "myClass": {
        "id": "myClass",
        "properties": {
            "myList": {
                "type": "string", //??? it isn't a string, it's a List...
                "allowableValues": {
                    "valueType": "LIST",
                    "values": [
                        "alpha",
                        "bravo",
                        "charlie"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this doesn't make sense either:

```
{
    "myEnum": {
        "id": "myEnum",
        "properties": {
            //??? there aren't any...
        }
    },
    "myClass": {
        "id": "myClass",
        "properties": {
            "myList": {
                "type": "List",
                "items": {
                    "$ref": "myEnum"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across [this post in the Swagger Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/0w-6PbPSIpY), which lead me to this answer:

```
{
    "myClass": {
        "id": "myClass",
        "properties": {
            "myList": {
                "type": "List",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "allowableValues": {
                    "valueType": "LIST",
                    "values": [
                        "alpha",
                        "bravo",
                        "charlie"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```